# ARC on iOS6 and xCode4.5

Tags: ios6, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.5

I use below code to test arc and help to understand the ARC

```
NSArray __strong*  myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123", nil];
NSArray __weak*  yourArray = myArray;
NSArray __unsafe_unretained*  theirArray = yourArray;
myArray = nil;
NSLog(@"yourArray = %@, theirArray = %@", yourArray, theirArray);
```

As my understand, the log should be:yourArray = (null), theirArray = (null)
In face the log is:
yourArray = (
    123
), theirArray = (
    123
)

if I change the code and remove the __unsafe_unretained:

```
NSArray __strong*  myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123", nil];
NSArray __weak*  yourArray = myArray;
//NSArray __unsafe_unretained*  theirArray = yourArray;
myArray = nil;
NSLog(@"yourArray = %@", yourArray);
```

the log is right:yourArray = (null)

why if I add __unsafe_unretained local variables to weak reference my NSArray object, it like retain or strong my NSArray object.

Any one can help to answer the doubt.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is pretty good about figuring out what object's lifetimes are during this kind of simple example with limited scope. It can tell that it shouldn't release the array until the end of the scope is reached (or at least the end of the last read is reached with these simple assignments).

If you use an ivar that's marked `__unsafe_unretained`, assign it after the weak assignment, and build with full optimizations, you might see different results, even in this kind of simple case. Also, basically while the compiler may be able to deal with situations like this, where the `__weak` variable is still set and the `__unsafe_unretained` variable is still able to be read without disaster, the point is that you can't *count* on it to behave that way. What you *can* count on is that a `__weak` variable will be nil'd out after its last `__strong` reference goes away, and that the compiler won't insert retain/release directives for an `__unsafe_unretained` variable. As long as you follow the rules, you will have predictable results. As soon as you don't follow the rules, anything that happens or doesn't happen is undefined... so it may work in the simulator and iPod 4G's but fail horribly on 4S and 5 while working half the time on any iPad... the point is, the result is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. __unsafe_unretained assign __weak is not a good way to programe. This result is base on xcode compiler, so this test result suggest me using __weak instead all the __unsafe_unretained, not cross reference.

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123", nil] is autoreleased and won't be deallocated until the autorelease pool has been flushed. The weak reference won't be nil'd out until the object is deallocated. The unsafe_unretained reference will never be nil'd out and will become invalid once the object is deallocated.

So the log should be

yourArray = ( 123 ), theirArray = ( 123 )

But later when the object gets deallocated, then it should be

yourArray = ( NULL ), theirArray = undefined

undefined because the pointer is invalid and could point to a new object or just garbage, it could even crash the code

Comment: If I change to [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"123", nil];  this return object is not autoreleased, but have the same problem.